# Lazily evaluation in scala with streams

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

Am I correct in assuming that the s1.toStream will avoid the creation of unneed tuples in the second line of the below function?

```
  def areEqual(s1: String, s2: String): Boolean = {
    if (s1.length != s2.length) false
    else (s1.toStream zip s2).forall { case (c1, c2) => c1 == c2 }
  }
             ^^^^^^^^
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right because `forAll` will return false as soon as the first pair c1, c2 is not equals, so it won't generate the following combinations.